# List Of Bits in java with Bit Data Type

Tags: java, list, types, bit

I need to create a list of bits in Java for a college project, and I am having troubles on how to assign the values. What I am trying to achieve is to create a

```
List<Bit> listOfBits = new ArrayList<Bit>();  //I create this without problem
```

and then, of course,

```
listOfBits.add(/*something with Bit data type*/) //I cannot add anything with Bit type
```

Anyone could please help me??

Thanks.

Comment: Have you written a class `Bit`? Or do you prefer just to use a `Boolean` that has 2 possible values just like a bit?

Comment: This is just a list inside a class...I am not allowed to create another separate class...I can use Boolean ,but I should be able to make this work: listOfBits.add(/*a boolean thing that has a Bit type*/)

Comment: What keeps you from simply using `Boolean`? What exactly are you trying to achive or what is your task?

Comment: Probably practically does not have much sense, it is a college exercise. What I am trying to achieve is as easy as build a list of Bit data type. I know is tricky..you know how to add a bit element into a Bit list data type? or even add bit values to Bit[]? I do not find anything with bit type...

Comment: @Jordi indeed you should, all we can say is you are doing something wrong. What is stopping you from doing this? What error do you get? BTW using BitSet would be a more natural choice.

Comment: @Jordi If you haven't created a `Bit` type, it doesn't exist. Check it wasn't given to you as part of the assignment.

Comment: good point with BitSet, "been there, done that" BitSet is BitSet data type, not bit...you cannot do listOfBits.add(/*setBit..*/), Bit is a recognized java type, right?

Comment: @Peter thanks, that would make sense...of course If I can create the class Bit, then things are quite straight forward...

Comment: Does the assignment contain how an example call to `listOfBits.add(x);` looks like? What goes to `x`?

Comment: problem with BitSet is that the data type that you get from it is NOT Bit, is BitSet

Comment: @tevemadar not it does not...

Comment: Most likely you are expected to write an actual class, but internally it can contain `List`, `BitSet` or any suitable kind of member variables...

Comment: Could you please explain what the task / assignment expects from you? Do you have to calculate with or just store bits?

Comment: @deHaar just store Bits...and show them...I think that the tricky part of the assignment is to store data as Bit type..probably I will go for creating the class, if Java does not have any Bit data type to add to a list of Bit...

Comment: Here is a list of all the built in classes, constants etc for Java 11 and there is no `Bit` type https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index-files/index-2.html

Comment: Why not use [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) as mentioned by @tevemadar?

Comment: @Jordi What is the exact text of the assignment? I think you can do it just using a `List<Boolean>` but to be sure, I have to read the assignment ;-). You could just edit it into your question.

Comment: @peter  I am using Java 10, so I assume that it also applies. I think that I have this question answered. I'll go for creating my class Bit, and if professor would not agree I will forward him the link to all Java types, and challenge him to find the primitive Bit data type. Thanks a lot guys. I think that I know what to do :)

Comment: @Jordi What would you say if you were asked to explain the data type *bit* in your context?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely need it to implement `List` you can use [java.util.BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html).